# Uploading image from Android to Python server

Tags: android, python

I'm wondering what libraries or frameworks to use in Python to read an image posted by an Android client.

So basically, the Android client gets an image file in the phone and sends it 
to the Python server via POST request. The only thing I read about when reading images in Python is via Sockets.

I would like to ask for links or some sample code on how to implement the Python server side for reading images via POST.

Comment: would you tried python image libraries like PIL(python imaging library)....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a backend web app which was python-flask based, it had this method to accept the images.

```
@app.route('/getNoteText',methods=['GET','POST'])
def GetNoteText():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['pic']
        filename = file.filename
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        processImage(filename)            
    else:
        return "Y U NO USE POST?"
```

And my android function which is calling this method looks like this

```
  /**
     * Uploading the file to server
     */
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;
            Log.d("Log", "File path" + opFilePath);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                           @Override
                          public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });
                ExifInterface newIntef = new ExifInterface(opFilePath);
                newIntef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,String.valueOf(2));
                File file = new File(opFilePath);
                entity.addPart("pic", new FileBody(file));
                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();


                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                    Log.d("Log", responseString);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode + " -> " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
                    Log.d("Log", responseString);
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;    
        }
    }
```

This is the File Upload URL, which refers to the webservice created above by my python app.

```
 public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://<localhost>:5000/getNoteText";
```

And we are fetching the image which has been taken and stored in the android file system and using the `UploadFileToServer` class like this:

```
 String filePath = Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) +
                            File.separator + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME;
                    File dirFile = mkDir(filePath);
                    File outputFile = new File(dirFile, String.format("%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    opFilePath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    UploadFileToServer uploadFileToServer = new UploadFileToServer();
                    uploadFileToServer.execute();
```

You can use this `uploadFileToServer` to send any type of files to the background. You do not need to be constrained to just images.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know this is a very old post but you should also use `secure_filename` from `werkzeug.utils` like this, `filename = secure_filename(file.filename)` because you should never trust any user input.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a tutorial that did this. It builds an Android app that uploads an image to a server created in Flask using Python. The tutorial is titled "[Uploading images from Android to a Python-based Flask Server](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/uploading-images-from-android-to-a-python-based-flask-server-691e4092a95e)"